# WebApi Json Id not retrieving where as all other fields are showing

Tags: jquery, json, rest, api, model-view-controller

I am very beginner in MVC and recently started to develop a test site using web apis, i have my api controller name CustomerController which return simple IEnumerable list of customers.

when i test my api using POSTMAN its shows record but Id shows 0 (id=0) below is the image for reference
        [Ids showing 0][1]
          [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MqUb.png

```
    below is my api/controller


        public class CustomersController : ApiController{
            private ApplicationDbContext _context;

            public CustomersController(){
                _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            }

            //GET api/Customer
            public IEnumerable<CustomerDto> GetCustomers(){
               return _context.Customer.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<Customer,CustomerDto>);
            }

>CUstomer MODEL

        public class Customer
        {
                public int id{ get; set; }
                [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
                [StringLength(255)]
                public string Name{ get; set; }
                public bool IsSubscribeToNewsLetter{ get; set; }
                public MembershipType MembershipType{ get; set; }
                [Display(Name = "Membership Type")]
                public byte MembershipTypeId{ get; set; }
                [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
                [Min18YearsIfMember]
                public DateTime? BirthDate{ get; set; }
        }
    }



>CUSTOMERDTO MODEL 


     public class CustomerDto
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
            [StringLength(255)]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public bool IsSubscribeToNewsLetter { get; set; }
            public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
            //[Min18YearsIfMember]
            public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        }
       <i/>
```

Comment: i am sorry i attached movies list image but the same problem occurring in customers too same problem

Comment: Can you show the Customer and CustomerDto models? Is it possible automapper can't find the correct match for Id?

Comment: @amburt05 please see my edited version of question, names of fields are same in both in DTO and in Model

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the reason for above issue : the issue was in my mapping profile in which i have mapped like this

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>().ForMember(c=>c.id, opt=> opt.Ignore());
  Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>().ForMember(c => c.id, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

in above mapping i have ignored the id field due to this my ids was showing as 0 when i edit my mapping to its simple like

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>();
  Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>();
```

by doing above changes my apis showing ids on my web page.
P.S as i am very beginner i still need to find the impact of above changes/